# W.D Gaster in actual timeline? (SPOILERS)

Tags: undertale

So I've been datamining Undertale, and I came across this one file called mysteryman, and I decided to delve deeper. I found out that this guy was called W.D. Gaster, and I altered the fun values and whatnot to get all of his black and white characters and Gaster himself to spawn. But what was the purpose of this "mysteryman" and does anyone know what kind of impact he has on the game?

Comment: Unsure if relevent, but apparently the latest patch has reinstated a single Gaster encounter, meaning that you no longer need to hack into the game's files to see him. I guess this makes him a canon character?

Comment: @DJAftershock Also unsure if relevant, but do you have a source for that claim anyway?

Comment: [this](http://napstamuse.tumblr.com/post/137706777152/guys-this-is-not-a-drill-you-no-longer-have-to) was the original post on Tumblr, Kotaku are also [quoted](http://steamed.kotaku.com/players-uncover-new-secrets-buried-in-undertales-first-1754156048) saying "Now there's apparantly an extremely slight chance that his room will appear at a specific point in the game sans tampering". I also know that to make this room appear previously, the "F" in the 'fun' stat HAD to be captalized. Seems that when Toby said "The F in fun is a bug", he meant that the room was always meant to be accessible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Gaster currently has no direct impact on the normal game, and unclear indirect impact, if any.**

Gaster never appears in the game or is even mentioned per se during normal gameplay. The only references which can be found to his existence can only be accessed through modification of game files in ways unintended for standard gameplay. Until and unless Toby Fox comes forth with some more information, an expansion to the game, or some other form of insight, the information that you've found through the game file modification is all there is.

Comment: There are some NPCs that do mention W. D. Gaster, but i'm not familiar with which NPCs or how to get to them.  Most are just vague references, while one specifically says W. D. Gaster (if i remember correctly).  Really the only thing that he has an impact on is the fact that he was the royal scientist until he fell into the core.  One of those NPCs specifically state he was shattered/spread among all of time and space.  Other than that, there's very little information about him and all references to him can be easily missed.

Comment: That sucks. I was so hyped for a 4th "secret" ending with Gaster. Well, rip in pieces Gaster, literally.

Comment: @dakre18 Those references are only found through modifying game files, namely "Fun" values, and thus aren't what I was referring to as the "normal game." Those characters were mentioned in the question (the "black and white characters"). But the information you mentioned is correct.

Comment: @MikeKellogg That's why i added it as a comment.  Someone might like knowing that, and it just adds to your answer (which is fine).